# PHP SESSION variable not working at the 1st time

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

Session variables are not set at the first time. From action.php it goes to employee.php But in employee.php $_SESSION['EmpID'] shows nothing when I log in for the 1st time. If I log out and log in again then works fine.  works fine in localhost.

```
action.php

<?php
session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['UserID'])&&isset($_POST['Password']))
{
$id = $_POST['UserID'];
$pass = $_POST['Password'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from auth_det where     UserName='$id' and Password='$pass'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//echo $row['UserID'];
//echo $row['Password'];
                $_SESSION['UserName']=$id;
                $_SESSION['EmpID'] = $row['EmpID'];
        $_SESSION['is_auth'] = true;
            $_SESSION['User'] = "Emp";
               echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = 'Employee/employee.php'; </script>";
                 exit();
```

}

```
logout.php
<?php
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = '../login.php'; </script>";
?>


employee.php

session_start(); 
$EmpID=$_SESSION['EmpID'];
echo "EmpID=".$EmpID;
if(!isset($_SESSION['EmpID']))
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location.href = 'logout.php'; </script>";
}
```

Comment: no code = no question

Comment: show youre code

Comment: Can you be more specific. Your question is too broad, provide codes and scenarios.

Comment: do you use session_start(); ?

Comment: yes.. session_start is there.

Comment: everything works fine. but not at the first time.

Comment: on the employee.php page Session variables holds nothing when I log in for the 1st time

Answer (score 0):

try to move the `session_start()` to the action.php file.
At first connect php doesn't create a session at `action.php`
Then you get redirected and `employee.php`  starts the session.
If you try this again later a session is already open so you have no problems at the action php.

Also think about switching the Javascript Redirect to an header redirect since it still works if the Client disabled Javascript

Comment: session_start() is there in the action.php file . But still the problem exists.

Comment: And header() also not working. hence i am using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

please check that you did'nt forgot to write `session_start();`  on the top of `action.php` page

Comment: session_start() is there in the action.php file . But still the problem exists.

Comment: i think this will work..create a `config.php` in which you have to write connection code followed by `session_start();` and include this file at the top of each page

Comment: Ok..I will try this.